# How to use control ID from clientside .ascx and use it in serverside ascx.cs (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET control defined in my .acsx and some code on the server side that checks it in my .cs, creating a new custom validator if the data input is invalid.

I am trying to make the error message display next to the control, but I am unable to set the `ControlToValidate` attribute to the `ID` of the control. Visual Studio highlights `ContactTelephoneTextBox` with the error:

> cannot convert source type

This is the Custom Validator in the .cs

```
Page.Validators.Add(new CustomValidator()
{
    Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic,
    ControlToValidate = ContactTelephoneTextBox, 
    ID = "phoneInvalid",
    IsValid = false,
    ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number.", 
    field",
});
```

In my .ascx

```
<div id="ContactTelephone">
    <asp:Label ID="ContactTelephoneLabel" AssociatedControlID="ContactTelephoneTextBox"
        CssClass="required formFont2015 formLabel2015" runat="server">Contact number</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="ContactTelephoneTextBox" CssClass="boxStyle2015" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ControlToValidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects a string not a control, so this should work:

```
Page.Validators.Add(new CustomValidator()
{
    Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic,
    ControlToValidate = ContactTelephoneTextBox.ClientID, 
    ID = "phoneInvalid",
    IsValid = false,
    ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number.", 
    field",
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This compiles and judging by the description of ClientID I'd expect this to work. But when invalid data is input the error message isn't displaying next to the control, any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: @ecclesm: why don't you add the validator declaratively(so on your aspx)? You know that you have to re-create all controls that were added dynamically on every postback?

Comment: Hi Tim, I haven't downvoted you, infact I don't have enough rep to upvote you yet, but your answer fixed the problem I asked about. I am unsure why anyone downvoted this.